# Get the SKPaymentTransaction for a FinishTransaction()

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, storekit

**tl;dr** How to `FinishTransaction` an in-app purchase **not** from within an `UpdatedTransactions` callback?

**Details**

Currently I have a `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` with an `UpdatedTransactions` callback which receives the `SKPaymentTransaction` needed in order to `FinishTransaction` of an in-app product.

But that forces the app to update my server with the transaction **from within the `UpdatedTransactions` callback**. I would like to change that and have the `UpdatedTransactions` just **start** the process of updating the server, and later, when the server has been updated, the app will `FinishTransaction` **not** from within the `UpdatedTransactions` callback.

My problem is - how do I get the `SKPaymentTransaction` which is required by the `FinishTransaction`?

Answers in both Apple-native languages or C#/Xamarin welcome.

Comment: Does [this](https://medium.com/@maximbilan/ios-swift-in-app-purchases-d8946e331d61) be helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

```
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
    for transaction in transactions {
        switch transaction.transactionState {
        case .purchasing: 
           updateTransactionToServer {
               queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
           }
        case .purchased: .....
    }
}

func updateTransactionToServer(completion:()->Void) {
    //logic to updated status to ur backed
}
```

you can do something like this, or you can refer to [link](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit)